# trying to make a recursive permutation function in python

Tags: python

I was trying to make a recursive permutation function in python but it only works for the inputs [0,1] and [0]

please help

```
def permutationHelper(lst):
    if len(lst)==0:
        return []
    elif len(lst)==1:
        return lst
    per=[]
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        perAtI = permutationHelper(lst[:i]) + permutationHelper(lst[i+1:])

        perAtI.insert(0,i)
        per.append(perAtI)
    return (per)
```

After reading ur comments i made this adjustments but still no luck

```
def permutationHelper(lst):
    if len(lst)==0:
        return []
    elif len(lst)==1:
        return lst
    per=[]
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        perAtI = permutationHelper(lst[:i]) + permutationHelper(lst[i+1:])
        for j in perAtI:
            if type(j)==list:
                j.insert(0,lst[i])
                per.append(perAtI)
            else:
                perAtI.insert(0,lst[i])
                per.append(perAtI)
     return(per)
```

Comment: What output do you expect, and what output do you get instead?  I can run lots of inputs and get all sorts of outputs from your code.  `permutationHelper([4,3,6])
Out[13]: [[0, [0, 6], [1, 3]], [1, 4, 6], [2, [0, 3], [1, 4]]]`  Are you looking for all unique permutations?

Comment: I think that might have to do with the fact that you are returning a list in the base cases, but returning a list of lists in the final step. this explains the nested levels in the output. The `insert(0,i)` is also problematic. Maybe you meant `insert(0, lst[i])`?

Comment: After i red ur comments i tried to fix the code this way but still no luck                          `perAtI = permutationHelper(lst[:i]) + permutationHelper(lst[i+1:])
  for j in perAtI:
         if type(j)==list:
                j.insert(0,lst[i])
                per.append(perAtI)
            else:
                perAtI.insert(0,lst[i])
                per.append(perAtI)
    return (per)`

Comment: Why to invent the wheel when you already have one? https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: its an assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking multiple times I corrected the code into what is posted below and it worked fine

```
def permutationHelper(lst):
    if len(lst)==0:
        return []
    elif len(lst)==1:
        return [lst] # this should have been a list within a list
    per=[]
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        perAtI = permutationHelper(lst[:i]+lst[i+1:]) #should have been concatenated before passing into the function
        for j in perAtI:
            if type(j)==list:
                j.insert(0,lst[i])
                per.append(perAtI)
            else:
                perAtI.insert(0,lst[i])
                per.append(perAtI)
     return(per)
```